# Getting the CSS right on a sticky bar in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a header that UX/UI has made on an inhouse project. Above the header there's a closeable bar. I want to have it sticky so that it's above the header and not on the header. I'm having trouble getting the CSS right. I can't seem to move the X mark to the right while keeping the rest of the text centered.
Here is my code (heavily modified and probably a bit to much trying to get it right.

JSX:

```
<>
        {!bar && (
            ""
        )}
        {bar && (<div className="barClass">
            <div className="pClass">
                <p className="somethingP"> Something very important!</p>
                <p className="readMoreLink">Read more</p>
            </div>
            <div className="buttonClass">    
                <button className="barButton" type="button" onClick={removeBar} >X </button>
            </div>
            
        </div>)}
       

        </>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.barClass {
    background-color: rgb(196,49,196);
    position: sticky;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
}

.somethingP {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.readMoreLink {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.pClass {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.buttonClass {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.barButton {
    align-self: flex-end;
    background-color:rgb(196,49,196) ;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get it, your concern here is to position the close button to the right. One way to do it would be like that :

```css
.barButton {
    position: absolute; /* allow us to position it where we want on the bar*/
    top: 50%; /* this will put the top of the close button to the center of 
 the bar */
    right: 20px; /* Arbitrary, it's up to you*/
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* trick to make the button to go up by 50% of its proper height, so it will be perfectly vertically centered*/
    background-color:rgb(196,49,196) ;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Nice ! You can mark my answer as correct so it will help future people ! Have a nice day.